# Oracle - selecting constant values as M x N table from dual

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently I'm using something similar to following statement for creating a temporary table like structure.

```
WITH CONFIGURATION AS (
   SELECT 'some blah value' AS BLAH , 'some blee value' AS BLEE FROM DUAL
   UNION
   SELECT 'some other blah value' AS BLAH, 'some other blee value' AS BLEE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 'BLAH BLAH' FROM CONFIGURATION C, SOME_OTHER_TABLE T WHERE C.BLAH=T.BLAH
```

**The problem that I'm facing here is that the query becomes considerably large and messy when I have to implement the same structure for a 10x7 table structure.**

Is there any easier way to achieve this using `DUAL` or any other system tables without having to use `UNION` and rewrite the `SELECT FROM DUAL` multiple times?

> **NOTE:**
>
> - **I have no DDL permission on this database. Otherwise I would have created a table for achieving this already**
> - **The database version is oracle 11g**
> - **The data inside the M x N structure is to be will be irregular in nature**

Comment: This is a good approach considering you have DML privileges. If correctly formatted, no longer how long the statements are it will be readable and maintainable.

Comment: With Oracle Subquery Factoring, you can have multiple unique statements in your WITH clause and "daisy-chain" them together through use of aliases and a comma. Better use of aliases should make it easier to manage your WITH contents. Check out this site for examples: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql99_with_clause.htm

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` in your list of `select .. from dual` statements rather than `UNION`, to avoid doing unnecessary sorts/distincts. Also, if your data is such that you're unable to use the connect by suggested by @Mat, and you can't do DDL on the db (and there's no corresponding tables you could insert into), you're stuck with using `UNION ALL` to mimic your "table" of data.

Comment: Although, I suppose you could use PL/SQL to pop everything into an array, and then return a ref cursor querying directly against the array (via `TABLE()`). That assumes there's already a corresponding array database type already present, though.

Comment: So I'm stuck with this query then.

Comment: Pretty much. Sounds like you've got your hands tied, so there's not much you could do to improve things, beyond switching to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Yup, But I'm leaving the records to be distinct as the script that generates this sql may generate duplicate records which I don't want to entertain. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
select * from (
  select trunc( (rownum - 1) / 3) as x, mod(rownum - 1, 3) as y, column_value
  from table( dbmsoutput_linesarray(
           'some blah value' , 'some blee value', 'some bluuu value',
           'some other blah value', 'some other blee value', 'some other bluuu value',
           'blah 5', 'blee 5', 'bluu 5',
           'blah 6', 'blee 6', 'bluu 6'
                ))
)
pivot (
  max( column_value )
  for y in ( 0 as blah, 1 as blee, 2 as bluuu )
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is not only clean but it also reduces  the query size considerably when the data set is large. Thank you.